# Why/when should I define my variables in VBA Macros?

Tags: vba

I have never really defined my variables in my VBA Macros and it has all gone alright. There may have been a couple of times I have added them in, but not sure if it was really needed in the end.

So my question is, why is it needed? And when (as it is clearly not always needed as I'm done fine without)?

Thanks

Benji

Comment: If you share an example of your MACRO, we can suggest where it's recomended to use a variable, and where it's not

Comment: I have a LOT of macros. I was wondering if there were rules/best practice areas where they should be used.

Answer (score 2):

Explicitly declaring variables is generally a good idea. Some reasons are:

- it is clear when a variable is being declared (vs re-assigning value of existing variable)
- variable data type can be specified; this may be important:

  - because a variable may be given a more generic/abstract type than would otherwise be inferred by the compiler (eg declare a variable as a *parent class* or an *interface*)
  - to force certain casting or rounding behaviour at run-time (eg declare an Integer to store number of whole days past since 2017-01-01)

In VBA, a further [Option Explicit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y9341s4f.aspx) statement is available. When Option Explicit is **ON**, the code will not compile unless all variables are excplicitly declared. This prevents unintended behaviour from typos in variable names (ie it's not possible to accidentally create a variable by mistyping the name of an existing variable).

Answer (score 1):

the reasons why I would define my variables are

- performance reasons, to force VBA to use Long or Integer instead of Variant
- readability reasons, if others need to read and understand your code
- language constraints, sometimes you must define your arrays otherwise your program won't run
- ease of debugging reasons in combination with option explicit, to exclude some typo's in your code

The reason why I would not define my variables is

- less intructions (less characters) to code